# Upload modified image with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, canvas, form-data

I've got a form where the user can update their user avatar and modify their profile. As it is, it works fine, the user selects their photo and it uploads fine.

But I want to apply some modifications to the photo before it gets uploaded, resize, crop and rotate if necessary. I've got the modifications working fine, my problem is how can I replace the user selected file with my modified one?

I've tried appending the input name and file data into the FormData object but it's still using the user specified image.

This is my code so far:

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
var newImg   = canvasResize($('#member_avatar')[0].files[0], {
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        crop: true,
        quality: 100,
        callback: function(data, width, height) {
            formData.append("member_avatar", data);
        }
    });

$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method').toUpperCase(),
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can try using php that will process img or what about to create a function that will process the Img and it will return a ok and then It will call a Ajax

Comment: I'd rather have the processing done client-side, reduces strain on the server and reduces file size.

Comment: And you want to send a croped img to server right?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
     //After Click run this
                canvasResize($('#member_avatar')[0].files[0], {
                        width: 400,
                        height: 400,
                        crop: true,
                        quality: 100,
                        callback: function(data) {
                                 formData.append(function(){send()}, "member_avatar" , data);
                               }
                });
function send(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    type: form.attr('method').toUpperCase(),
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined'){
                            console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
                        }else{
                            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                    }
                })
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': No function was found that matched the signature provided`